# Strange compilation error with Maven

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I have a project A that depends on project B that depends on project C. Project C depends on Hibernate (more precisely org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.8.Final). Project B doesn't depend on the hibernate artifact. But, project A depends on this artifact but only for unit tests, so I use test scope. When I try to build A, projects C and B are correctly built and installed but I get the following error during A compilation:

> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>   myPackage\MyClass.class(myPackage:MyClass.class): warning: Cannot find
>   annotation method 'value()' in type
>   'org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade': class file for
>   org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade not found An exception has occurred
>   in the compiler (1.6.0_27). Please file a bug at the Java Developer
>   Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the
>   Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following
>   diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType not found

I precise that MyClass belongs to project C and imports org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade. And C compiles successfully so it can find the said class.
But here, it seems that the class file cannot be found during A compilation. I thought that maybe the test-scoped dependency on Hibernate may cancel the Hibernate dependency of C? But, I have no idea.

Also, if I change the scope of the dependency in project A from test to compile, the problem disappears.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure what you want from us, exactly; you found a compiler bug, and you should report it.

Comment: Is this a compiler bug? not a compilation error due to problems with my code?

Comment: It says right in the message you quote, "An exception has occurred in the compiler... Please file a bug..." So yes, it's not your fault!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's both a compiler bug and a bug in your code.

On your side:

You're overriding the scope of the transient hibernate dependency so it isn't available at compile time, only at test time.

The annotations being used in MyClass in project C are available at runtime (otherwise hibernate wouldn't be able to reference them when running your project).  This means that when you compile, javac needs to be able to load those annotations but it can't find them.

On the compiler's side side:

This should technically just be spit out with any other compiler generated errors/warnings.  However, somebody missed something on the compiler's side so the compiler is crashing instead of appending to the list of warnings.  I would recommend updating to the latest JDK, try again, and if it still doesn't work report a bug.

Comment: Thanks deterb, I learned that indeed I was overriding the scope of my hibernate dependency, but I got this error when I was thinking I was right. And, I still don't understand why I only get hibernate at test time, since I have a transitive dependency on the same artifact with a compile scope. Maybe you can help me with this at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923787/different-scopes-of-the-same-artifact-and-transitive-dependencies-issue. Thanks

Comment: I was also seeing this compiler exception with Java 1.6.0_26, but it turned into a regular warning with Java 1.7.0_11. That said, you of course still need to fix your code. In my case, I was using a library that depends on [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), but I was simply lacking the Jackson libraries in my class path.

Comment: Saw the same error, and the error message is very misleading. Thanks sschuberth's comment