# Different scopes of the same artifact and transitive dependencies issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a project A that use library L v1.0.0 with test scope. Project A also depends on project B (with scope compile), with B transitively depending on the library L v1.0.0 (with scope compile).

Why the final scope of the library L for project A is 'test'? It causes me NotClassDefFoundError at runtime. It seems that the dependency definition of project A on library L overrides those of the transitive dependencies on L.

What's wrong here? My project A only uses L for unit tests so I define the dependency with 'test' scope. But, at the end, I want L to be on my classpath since project A depends on project B for production, and B needs (transitively) library L.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Peter's suggestion, just leave L out of the dependencies for A. You should be able to access it anyway, and Maven will treat it as a `compile`-scoped dependency.

This hides that A's tests depend on L, though.

Comment: I know that there are some tricks like this (that's what I used for now), but I don't understand why this is not automatically included with 'compile' scope. Is there an explanation or this is a lack of feature?

Comment: It allows you to specifically state the scope you are after. Could be that L is 'provided' on the runtime system, so A only needs it for testing.
IMO, what's missing (for your case) is a feature to specify the scope independently for testing and production.

Comment: But Maven knows that on the paths to project B (in the dependency tree), dependencies on L have compile scope. Why it can't decide that L is necessary for compile here? It seems like a bug... My project A uses L for unit tests, but there are transitive dependencies on L with compile scope, I can deduce that the final scope has to be compile, because I would need it on my path.

Comment: Yes, it could - but then the next guy would come with the inverse question: "Why does maven add L to the classpath? I explicitly told it that I only need it for testing."
Bug or not, Maven makes very strong assumptions about what you need, and behaves accordingly.
Don't get me wrong, I'm far from being a Maven evangelist - I've just accepted it for what it is (and moved on to Gradle if circumstances allow.)

Comment: I don't know why one would want Maven to chose the test dependency in this case, one of its compile dependencies depends on L so he needs L on the classpath. So, my thoughts are that this assumptions is wrong unless someone finds me a use case for the contrary.

Comment: The best way to look at this is that the highest level project may need a way to "manage", tweak, or override the dependencies of other projects.  Each of these overrides is a complete replacement of the definition of that dependency, so the test scope will override the compile scope.  I think the best example for this behavior is the "provided" scope, which basically says "it'll be available at runtime", for managing shared dependencies on a servlet container.  Your libraries probably don't know this, and using their rules could mess up deployments.

Comment: As another follow on, there are alternate build setups where different rules are in effect - in particular I'm thinking of an old maven setup for OSGI where transitive dependencies aren't available at compile time unless you specify them.  I'm sure you could write your own maven packing and dependency resolution configuration that has the exact behavior you're looking for with some effort.

Comment: Then again, avoiding a headache like that is exactly why one uses Maven in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Maven? In that case, if I remember correctly Maven will use the "nearest" definition to determine the actual scope. In this case module A specifies test and the transitive scope from B is overridden, because A is nearest since you're actually in A :)
This gets more complicated when you have multiple modules with dependencies between them.
A common cure is to define all dependencies (and scopes and versions) in a common parent Pom.xml in the `<dependencyManagement>` tag.

Comment: The tag is '<dependencyManagement>'. 

You wrote it, but it isn't displayed on some browsers. I have nothing else to add to your answer, so I can't edit it. (6 changed characters minimum.)

Comment: Even if I declare the dependency to L (with compile scope) in the common parent POM, if the dependency on L declared in the POM of A has 'test' scope, the final scope stays 'scope'. I see that you can force to use a special version but not to use a special scope, using this way. The only solution I see for now is the one of UrsReupke.

Comment: You wouldn't need to set the scope to test in A since that would be compile and this test as well :). Maven behaves like this and we have to accept it and act accordingly, I'm not a big fan myself :)